# Using export default in order to export two objects values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to export two objects but once i import it I get `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` I'm wondering if there is a different way to make the export

```
export default {
  copy: data => copy({
    margin: margins.size,
    data
  }),
  cleanDisplay: () => clean(margin.size, 'success')
}
```

```
import component from '../../component'
```

Comment: how are you importing these in other files?

Comment: Could be that the error is not in the export or import, could be on de definition of the functions `copy` and `clean`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should be fine, are you importing them correctly?

```
import test from './test';

console.log(test);
```

Comment: yes, thats how im using import